# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' (c#)

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(1+"*"+i+"="+i*1);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see anything wrong with this code part. Can you please be more specific? On which line for example? Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: So you want to add an integer with the value `1` to a string containing an asterisk and add the current value of `i` to that ... ? You need to pick _one_ data type, e.g. `string`, and concatenate various substrings, e.g. `i.ToString()`, to arrive at your result.

Comment: Is your problem resolved? You have not provided any more information as requested, nor accepted an answer. If your issue has been resolved, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

From the title of the post, I'm guessing your error is coming from where you're reading the console input, not from where you're writing the result (you haven't been very clear on where the error is thrown. A stacktrace might be useful).

When you're getting user input to parse, you are better assigning the value to a string, then using TryParse, rather than just parse.

```
String inString = Console.ReadLine();
int i = 0;
bool parsedNumber = Int32.TryParse(inString, out i);
if (parsedNumber) {
    //Do Something with your lovely new Int32
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a try/catch block.

```
String inString = Console.ReadLine();
try {
    i = Int32.Parse(inString);
    //Do something with your int here
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Not a number
}
```

If I understand what you're asking, you want your output to look something like this...

1*1 = 1

1*2 = 2

...etc.

If so, you are better off calculating the product of the sum, and using a string builder to put the output together.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{ 
    int res = i * 1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("1 * ").Append(i).Append(" = ").Append(res);
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Mark's answer of using the overload for WriteLine is perfectly valid too, as would be the following use of String.Format

```
String outString = String.Format("1*{0}={1}", i, i*1);
Console.WriteLine(outString);
```

Using the overload for Console.WriteLine as Mark suggests is cleaner code, but by using String.Format, you can check the value of the string before it is written.

There's a few ways to achieve this formatting. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, one may be more suitable than the other.

Answer (score -1):

As i understand you can use this code to convert to int. ( Not Tested for your example ).

```
 switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                int Val = Int32.Parse(1+"*"+i+"="+i*1);
                Console.WriteLine(Val);
            }
            break;
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

or better you can use ( Int32.TryParse ) which returns true if the conversion succeeded.

```
switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
              int Val;

              if (Int32.TryParse(1+"*"+i+"="+i*1, out Val))
               {
                // TryParse returns true if the conversion succeeded.
               }
            }
            break;
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Calling Int32.Parse(1+"*"+i+"="+i*1) is effectively saying 'convert the string 1*1=1 into an Int32', which will throw a parse exception.